# How to clear cache in iOS ADAL library

Tags: ios, iphone, caching, adal

I have integrated ADAL library in my iOS application to authenticate with WAAD accounts. After receiving the accessToken then the login screen (of ADAL) automatically gets disappear. Now if I try to call same login code to login with different user then it does not showing any fresh login screen and it was automatically getting logged in with previous user and giving me new accessToken. How can I erase cache of previous logged in user. I used below code to clear cache but no use of it.

```
  [authContext.tokenCacheStore removeAll]; // This method is no more available. Getting error for removeAll method. 
  [authContext.tokenCacheStore removeAllWithError:&error]; // It does not clear cache.
```

Is there any way to clear cache or to display login screen? please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The same problem actually. Did you get any answer?

Comment: Yes, I set promptBehavior to AD_PROMPT_REFRESH_SESSION with method [authContext acquireTokenWithResource:resourceId
                                             clientId:clientId
                                          redirectUri:redirectUri
                              promptBehavior:AD_PROMPT_REFRESH_SESSION
                                               userId:nil
                                 extraQueryParameters:nil
                                      completionBlock:^(ADAuthenticationResult *result) { }];

Comment: Thanks @GaneshGuturi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache removal means deleting of tokens from the keychain. It has no impact on the cookies in the webview. You should use peomptbehavior.always flag to ensure that the user is prompted for password at login time.

Comment: Thank you Kanishk. I set promptBehavior to AD_PROMPT_REFRESH_SESSION and it does work for me.